# add custom links to series / data sections in pie chart (highcharts.js)

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am simply trying to allow each data section or series of a pie chart via [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs) to be clickable, eg. Shop section should link to `#shop_section` I've found demos where a global link was set to every data section in a chart. But I simply would like a unique `#link` to be accessible via clicking one of my three data sections / series.

```
   series: [{
        innerSize: '30%',
        data: [
            ['Shop', 10], 
            ['Buy', 10], 
            ['Own', 10], 
        ]
    }]
});
```

This didn't work: *(attempt)*

```
    data: [
        {name: 'Shop', 10, url: 'http://my_site1.com'},
        {name: 'Buy', 10,  url: 'http://my_site2.com'},
        {name: 'Own', 10,  url: 'http://my_site3.com'}
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plotOptions` would do the work:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series:{
            point:{
                events:{
                    click: function(){
                        window.location.href = this.url;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
```

By simply using a series->point->events we can speficy which events to delegate to our series points (in the case of a pie chart a point is a "slice").
On the event handler function itself, `this` refers to the clicked point, therefore I can directly use the custom property `url` you've set.

Comment: This looks great but how to specify which section links eg. name 'Shop' slice?

Comment: Hey @JamesBond, please clarify what your'e trying to achieve :) I didn't fully understand. the above code would work also for sections links

Answer (score 2):

Your series is incorrect, it should be:

```
data: [
    {name: 'Shop', y: 10, url: 'http://my_site1.com'},
    {name: 'Buy', y: 10,  url: 'http://my_site2.com'},
    {name: 'Own', y: 10,  url: 'http://my_site3.com'}
]
```

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo, which doesnt work.